# Integral of product of trigonometric functions with different frequencies

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Let $n,k,p $ be positive integers.
Is there a closed form for the integral
$$\int_0^\pi \sin(n x)^2 \sin(k x)^{2p-1} \, dx \qquad ?$$
If $n=k$, from [Wallis' integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals) we have
$$ \int_0^\pi \sin(n x)^{2p+1} \, dx = \dfrac{2}{n} \dfrac{ (2^p p!)^2}{ (2p+1)!}.  $$
What can we say for the case $n \neq k$ ?

Comment: You may just take the proof of Wallis' formula and adapt it to your case, it is not so different.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Unfortunately, for what I understand, the standard proof (for example the one on wikipedia) relies on an integration by parts trick which requires $n=k$.

Comment: $n=k$ is not a necessary condition to apply integration by parts.